# how to embed you tube private video in my moodle course

Tags: php, video, moodle

I am using moodle 3.1 version. I am new be in moodle.
I have embeded you tube private video in my course as this video is private so cant play this video in moodle.
So what setting i have to make in this, please help me in this.

Comment: You can't share private video, but can share unpublished video. But there is no way for a certain youtube video to be played only in a certain website.

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the private video in Moodle as a file.

Moodle will notice it is a video and will serve (play) it for all authorized users.

H.264 is probably the best format, but have a look at http://blog.zencoder.com/2013/09/13/what-formats-do-i-need-for-html5-video/